# Verify the spectral radius $r(A) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}||A^n||^{1/n}$.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, self-learning, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to Verify the spectral radius $r(A) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|A^n\|^{1/n}$.

Where $A$ is a matrix.

I have a proof that involves Jordan Blocks. The proof is long and involved but it not to hard to understand. I am interested in knowing if there is an easier (shorter) proof that does not involve using Jordan Blocks.

Any help and comments are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems to me it doesn't get any shorter than using Jordan blocks. You just have to look at the largest block corresponding to the eigenvalue with largest modulus. So claim reduces to $A = \lambda I + N$ where $N$ has 1's on the superdiagonal. That's not the only argument (the theorem holds in general Banach algebras) but doesn't get any simpler than that, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an alternative proof, you can use the fact that $A^k\rightarrow 0$ (as $k\rightarrow\infty$) iff $r(A)<1$ (which might also involve Jordan blocks, but can be proved also, e.g., using the Schur decomposition).

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a matrix norm. First, since $r(A)^k=r(A^k)\leq\|A^k\|$, we have $r(A)\leq\|A^{k}\|^{1/k}$. Next, let $\epsilon>0$ and $B=A/(r(A)+\epsilon)$. Since $r(B)=r(A)/(r(A)+\epsilon)<1$, $B^k\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ and hence there is an $N$ such that $\|B^k\|<1$ for $k\geq N$. This means that $\|A^k\|<(\rho(A)+\epsilon)^k$ (if $k\geq N$). Hence for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that $\rho(A)<\|A^k\|^{1/k}\leq\rho(A)+\epsilon$ for $k\geq N$. Consequently, $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\|A^k\|^{1/k}$ exists and is equal to $\rho(A)$.